# Antd - Is it possible to change the row expand icon in version 3.6.x

Tags: reactjs, antd

The default is [+] and [-].
and i want to increase this button size.
but i can't find the way in antd v.3.6.x...
Could not find a way to change it for more big size?

Thank you!!!

Comment: You can override style via css.

Comment: Which component do you use?

Answer (score 1):

### For antd version 3.6.x (for v3.1.x)

You can customize the css class `.ant-table-row-expand-icon`

```css
.ant-table-row-expand-icon{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

### For antd version 4.x

You can use `expandIcon` property to resize or change the icon, increase the `fontSize` to increase size of the icon

```js
<Table
    columns={columns}
    expandable={{
      expandedRowRender: (record) => (
        <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{record.description}</p>
      ),
      rowExpandable: (record) => record.name !== 'Not Expandable',
      expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) =>
        expanded ? (
          <MinusOutlined
            style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}
            onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)}
          />
        ) : (
          <PlusOutlined
            style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}
            onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)}
          />
        ),
    }}
    dataSource={data}
  />
```

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Antd Version < V4.x, you have to change the antd css directly.

Antd Version > V4.x. You can refer to the Ant Desing Doc codepen and style the expandIcon you want.

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    expandable={{
      expandedRowRender: record => (
        <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{record.description}</p>
      ),
      expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) =>
        expanded ? (
          <MinusCircleTwoTone style={{ fontSize: "150%"}} onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
        ) : (
          <PlusCircleTwoTone style={{ fontSize: "150%"}} onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
        )
    }}
```

codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-bird-nuzpr?file=/index.js:1270-1684